# Issue wih using backPressed in a webview and at the same time navigating within fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have a simple code that works fine. It starts with frag1 calls frag2 then frag3. The back button works fine too.

I use this code to instantiate the fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Frag2 f2 = new Frag2();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f2);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
```

At the same time I have a WebView in one of the fragment and I want to navigate the web so I added this code inside :

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        WebView webView = null;
        if(webView == null) return;

        if(webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

and it works well BUT I lose the fragment back button.

I tried to move the backpressed inside the fragment that instantiates WebView but I get the msg: method does not override method fom its super class.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid error. It works well wit this code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(webView != null && webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

previously I was never going to super.onBackPressed();